# Doctrine cascading remove on joins does not call the join preRemove lifecycle callback

Tags: symfony, orm, callback, doctrine, lifecycle

I've got Student and Course entities, both in a OneToMany on a join entity, StudentCourse.  This join has an added field of isCredited.

StudentCourse's referenced entities are cascading their deletions (whenever a Student or Course is deleted, all the StudentCourses associated with it are also deleted)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Course", inversedBy="students", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
$private course
```

My problem is, **whenever I delete a Course, the StudentCourses associated with it are also deleted by the cascade operation, but each StudentCourse has a preRemove lifecycle callback that needs to be called before this deletion occurs.  That's not happening**, and I *need* it to happen or I'm going to have to refactor everything to perform a mess of logic within the controllers for each entity.

This is the function not being called, but necessary because it updates the Student.

```
 /** @ORM\PreRemove */
public function preRemove()
{
  //if students hours should be de-credited
  if ($this->getIsCredited()) {
    //find out what category we should credit them for, add that courses hours to students hours for that category
    if ($this->getCourse()->getCategory() == 'Infrastructure') {
      $this->getStudent()->setInfraHrs(
        $this->getStudent()->getInfraHrs() - $this->getCourse()->getHours()
      );
    } else if ($this->getCourse()->getCategory() == 'Safety') {
      $this->getStudent()->setSafetyHrs(
        $this->getStudent()->getSafetyHrs() - $this->getCourse()->getHours()
      );
    } else if ($this->getCourse()->getCategory() == 'EDC') {
      $this->getStudent()->setEdcHrs(
        $this->getStudent()->getEdcHrs() - $this->getsCourse()->getHours()
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I thought about just doing this from a Course preRemove function, by iterating through `$this->getStudents()`, but I need that `$isCredited` field from the actual join to see if each StudentCourse is credited or not.  So that idea won't work.

Comment: A related [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3988)